# My computer won't boot, and I don't have another device to install usb repair tools

Tags: windows-7, linux, boot, bios

So, I recently uninstalled Linux on my Hp Elitebook 8570p. It came installed with Windows 7, so, I booted into windows 7 to delete the Linux partition. When I restarted my computer, it won't start! I get the following error:

Boot Device not found, Please install an operating system on your hard disk

I don't have a live USB available in order to do repairs: it would have been simple enough to use boot repair. But, I found an option in my BIOS where I can change my boot method into UEFI, and I can then enter a custom boot path into the BIOS to boot from. So I wanted to ask, what is the boot path for windows 7?

Comment: Probably C:\ ?  But, is there a possibility (often F9 or shift + F9, but google for your laptop model) to repair Windows? The worry, though, is that it might format the drive and lose your data. Your best seems to be to use another PC, or a USB stick with some rescue software installed. Good luck :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you had to switch the firmware *to* UEFI mode, it probably means the original Windows 7 installation wasn't for UEFI. And if it wasn't an UEFI installation, then there **won't be** an UEFI-compatible bootloader anywhere on the system – it'll only have a BIOS-compatible bootsector instead.

*(I mean, that's why "UEFI" and "BIOS" are different modes to begin with.)*

But if the Windows 7 installation *was* made in UEFI mode originally, then the bootloader path is (case-insensitive, and relative to the EFI system partition):

```
\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a path for legacy BIOS?

Comment: No. There is _no such thing_ as a "boot path" in BIOS systems – the boot methods of BIOS and UEFI are fundamentally different.